# IF condition is met, start loop at beginning (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

Using ruby 1.9.3, I need to do the following:

```
test_ids.each do |x|
    if x == 1
        y = x+1
    elsif x == 2
        y = x+2
    elsif x == 3
        (end loop here, start over with next test_id)
    else
        y = x+4
    end
end
```

I just need the loop to continue with the next object in the array if a condition is met instead of continuing throughout the script. How is this possible?

EDIT:

The end goal is something like this:

```
case x
    when 1
        abort
    when 2
        ...
    else
        ...
end

puts x+2
```

So as you can see, `x` is being used after the if case statement. I need to not run the `puts` statement if `x = 1`. I don't want to `abort` the script and terminate it altogether, I just want to skip that array object and go to the next one. Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt this does what you expect. `=` assigns a value to `x` so your code only executes `x = 1` inside the loop. Instead you need a comparison using `==`.

Comment: It's important to understand that, given the code you have, a `next` will do nothing special. Once the `elsif x == 3` matches and your code falls into that block, when it exits it's going to fall through and implicitly do a `next`. The only time you'd need a `next` is if there is additional code after the `end` statement you wanted to avoid. No other `elsif` statements would be executed nor would `else` occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `next` command.

```
test_ids.each do |x|
  if x == 1
    y = x+1
  elsif x == 2
    y = x+2
  elsif x == 3
    next
  else
    y = x+4
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, `next`. Simple enough. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`=` assigns a value to `x` so your code only executes `x = 1` inside the loop.

Instead you need a comparison using `==` in your `if` statements.

You could have avoided this using a `case` statement:

```
case x
when 1
  ...
when 2
  ...
when 3
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

In my experience using `case` tends to clarify code compared to multiple `if/else/elsif`.

Comment: Indeed, I just left off my `==`. And I agree case is more preferable, thanks for that tip. I'm still a little confused though. I edited my question for more clarification.